# How can I create an Application using Automator that will open a file from finder in VS Code as a new window?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I've found many answers and solutions that partially solve this but I can't seem to put it together.

To expand on the title, I want to be able to double click on a file and open it in VS Code as a new window.

On the CLI, I would run `code -n /path/to/file`, and I would like to execute this by double clicking on a file in Finder AND be able to right click on a file type and Open With as well.

Comment: Associate the file type with VSCode. No need for Automator. 'Open With...' should already show if there is a default association for that filetype.